# Intermittent error during batch predictions on custom container model in Vertex AI

Tags: docker, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a strange issue that appears intermittently during batch prediction calls on a custom container model in Vertex AI. Mods: I understand this is ambiguous, but so is error message I'm getting from Vertex, so cut me some slack, please!

### Background

We developed a custom video intelligence model container that actually contains three models (I know, bad form. It's a proof of concept and we're in the process of modularizing it). Local runs of the container works as expected with videos of all sizes applicable to our use case. Video size ranges from 40mb to 300mb. I run docker locally with 4gb of RAM, and despite the small RAM config, all models and the video(s) fit and run as expected.

In our web application that we've developed, we were using standard POST requests to upload videos to an external API (not cloud storage). The model container downloads the video from the same during inference. To accommodate App Engine's outbound request size limit of 32mb, we implemented chunked requests for video upload, which works as expected.

Unfortunately, this is when the error started to appear:

```
('Post request fails. Cannot get predictions. Error: Exceeded retries: Got Exception ConnectionError(ProtocolError(\'Connection aborted.\', RemoteDisconnected(\'Remote end closed connection without response\'))) when sending data {"instances": [{"some data": "goes here}]} to https://model-resource:predict.', 1)
```

Another error that appeared shortly after:

```
'Post request fails. Cannot get predictions. Error: Exceeded retries: Non-OK result 504 (upstream request timeout) from server, retry=3, ellapsed=600.02s.', 1)
```

We're using `n1-standard-4` VM and a T4 GPU, which again ran flawlessly prior to the chunked request implementation.

### Attempted Fixes

Honestly, I'm at a loss because there is no usable information in either of those error messages. However, we suspected we had some file name clashes so we made everything unique and we programmatically remove any files saved to the file system after the run is completed.

If I knew more about what causes this error I can implement the fix, but I'm hesitant to start chopping things up and wasting time without knowing what's causing this problem since our prediction runs last over an hour.

Answer (score -1):

I have the exact same issue, and curiously enough, in the second error I have the same "ellapsed=600.02s". My guess is that one of the inner services that VertexAI uses has a 600 seconds time out. Although I couldn't find any documentation saying so.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34634471)